# Why is this one variable being affected?

Tags: java, variables, scope

This is my first question at StackOverflow. This is the code in question:

```
public class ListStuff {
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    String[] randomNames = {"Herbie", "Jaco", "Pat", "Michael"};        
    String[] reversedNames = revertNames(randomNames);

    for (int i = 0; i < reversedNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(reversedNames[i]);
    }   
  }

  public static String[] revertNames(String[] s) {

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length / 2; i++) {
       String tmp = s[s.length - 1 - i];
       s[s.length - 1 - i] = s[i];
       s[i] = tmp;
    }  

  return s;
  }
}
```

This code runs fine and the `reversedNames` variable prints as reverted; no complaints there. My main concern, however, is that when I do the `String[] reversedNames = revertNames(randomNames);`, the variable `randomNames` also gets reverted. I do in no place change the `randomNames` variable with a `randomNames = blabla;`, so I fail to see why that variable keeps changing into a reverted version of itself, even though I am only passing it as an argument.

I have been programming for approximately one year, and my knowledge of variable scopes and such is very limited. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

Arrays in Java are reference types. This means that when you pass your array to the `revertNames` method, any change inside that method will also be seen outside. Since you are changing the array parameter `s` inside `revertNames` with this code:

```
String tmp = s[s.length - 1 - i];
s[s.length - 1 - i] = s[i];
s[i] = tmp;
```

the original array `randomNames` that was passed in place of `s` is also changed in the process.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are passing the array by reference, rather than by value. Essentially, this means that the `reversedNames` array still points to the `randomNames` array, so changing one will change the other.

Here is a diagram of the variables:

Initially:

```
randomNames
```

As we enter the `revertNames` function:

```
randomNames <-------- s
```

The `s` array still points back to the `randomNames` array! Thus, when we change `s`, we change `randomNames` as well.

As we leave the function:

```
randomNames <--------- s <--------- reversedNames
```

Thus, `reversedNames` points to `randomNames`.

After the function is finished calling:

```
randomNames <--------- reversedNames
```

Although the `s` array has disappeared, `reversedNames` still points to `randomNames`.

To fix the issue, create a temporary variable inside the `revertNames` function:

```
public static String[] revertNames(String[] oldarray) {
    // Create temporary array to avoid affecting original array
    String[] s = oldarray.clone();
    ...
```

Comment: Wow. Fastest response ever, great anwers guys, I will look into this and play with variations =)

Comment: I changed my vote now... The initial response didn't offer any insight into the issue. +1

Answer (score 1):

Within the body of revertNames you have a variable s, this is a reference to an object which is an array. The actual array is the array randomNames. So you are indeed changing values in the source array.

If you use Arrays.copy() you can get an indepedent array to work in - the copy will point to the same strings as the original array, but as Strings are immuatable that's safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : StringBuffer:reverse()

some thing like that :

```
public class t {
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    String[] randomNames = {"Herbie", "Jaco", "Pat", "Michael"};        
    StringBuffer rev;
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNames.length; i++) 
    {
       rev=new StringBuffer(randomNames[i]);
        System.out.println(rev.reverse().toString());
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are reference types, i.e. if you declare

```
String[] randomNames;
```

you have declared a local variable that holds a reference to an object that is an array of strings.

The statement

```
String[] otherNames = randomNames;
```

will copy the content of variable randomNames to the variable otherNames, but the content is just a reference. That is, this statement causes both otherNames and randomNames to refer to the same array object.

The same happens when you pass a `String[]` as method parameter. That is, the local variable `s` in `revertNames`, and the local variable `randomNames` in `main` will contain identical references, i.e. refer to the same array object. That is, the state of that array object will be visible though both `s` and `randomNames`.

Strictly speaking, this has nothing to do with scoping, because the variable `randomNames` is not modified (i.e. it still points to the same array). What is modified is the object it refers to.